# Mongodb geospatial query for searching lat, long within a radius

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-query

I am trying to get  the results based on geospatial query of mongodb within a circle of 5 km radius of a given lat,long.

For that i am using this query

```
{coords : 
    { $nearSphere :{ 
            $geometry: {
                       type : "Point",
                       coordinates : [ data.longitude, data.latitude]
                       },
             $maxDistance: 5000
                  }
          }
 }
```

But it is giving me undefined output. But when i  remove the $maxDistance it is giving me all the results. I want to get the results only under the specified maxDistance.

Comment: What type of index is defined on this field? Is is "2d" or "2dsphere"? And what are the coordinates in both your query and data? With a GeoJSON object in data the "distance" is measured in meters. Otherwise it is radians.

Comment: I added both 2d and 2dsphere

Comment: coordinates are in lat and long Number

Comment: Well you can only use one. Remove the 2d. Then actually tell people which coordinates you are querying with and at least one coordinate set you want to match. If we cannot prove or disprove we cannot answer.

Comment: Cool. Thanks it is working now. Sorry, i am bit new in asking questions. Next time i will give maximum information.

Comment: Guessing mostly it was the conflict in resolving either the "2d" or "2dsphere" index. The Help Center from the "Help" menu option has articles that explain good practices such as http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Providing the data you are supplying in a query and a small sample from which you expect a match is good practice. Give people something they can try, show what you expect as a result, and you get answers. Otherwise we prod you to get the information (if you are lucky) or otherwise just walk away.